# How to use the ½ key on a Chromebook with a Scandinavian keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard, chromebook

My son has a Dell Chromebook with a Scandinavian keyboard layout.

In the upper left, just below the <kbd>esc</kbd> button, we have a button with <kbd>§</kbd>, <kbd>|</kbd> and <kbd>1/2</kbd> symbol.

We have managed to get <kbd>§</kbd> and <kbd>|</kbd>, but no key combination works for the <kbd>1/2</kbd> symbol.

How can that be done?

[image: Chromebook keyboard]

Comment: Could you specify the exact layout name set in Windows or Linux? Like Swedish, Norwegian or Finnish. What is the keyboard layout that is specified on the box or keyboard itself? @awe

Comment: I think the hardware is a combined version for Norwegion/Swedish/Dansish, as the keys for Æ Ø Å has different alternatives shown on same keys, but the actual setup we use is for Norwegian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think the hardware is a combined version for
> Norwegion/Swedish/Dansish, as the keys for Æ Ø Å has different
> alternatives shown on same keys, but the actual setup we use is for
> Norwegian.

Awe

The Norwegian keyboard layout doesn't have the ½ symbol by default. 
[image]

[Norwegian Keyboard layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Keyboard_Layout_Norwegian.png)

BUT here is a trick for you and anybody else.

There is something called Ascii characters. You can use them for instances where your keyboard is limited in regards to characters you always have and is missing some that you need.

To get for example ½ hold ALT (key) and type 171 via the Num Pad, then release ALT (key).

Here additional examples:

- ALT + 225 = ß
- ALT + 137 = ë
- ALT + 126 = ~

There are plenty more but for the sake of your use ALT + 171 should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW; As Chrome OS is somehow a sibling to Linux;
On Ubuntu 20.04.3:

The key alone -> `§`
SHIFT -> `½`
AltgGr -> `¶`
AltGr+SHIFT -> `¾`
`|` is present on the key just to the right of left SHIFT (produces the character with AltGr),
and to the left of backspace (upper right, a dead key for `` - twice )
can't tell how to use that key to create / type a `|`

Now, no idea what Chrome OS uses as sv_SE-keyboard setting.